# Grouping data tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have following table in an Excel file:

```
customer ID sell    attribute1  attribute2  attribute3  ……  attribute N
Customer1   sell1   1               0            1              1   
Customer1   sell2   0               0            0              0   
Customer1   sell3   1               0            1              1   
Customer2   sell4   0               0            0              1   
Customer2   sell5   1               0            1              0   
Customer3   sell6   1               0            0              0   
……  ……
```

I need  an Excel VBA function to remove redundant customers rows and produce only one row for each customer represent the all columns values for that customer ... ( max value for each column produce only maximum values in that column ), column sell its not consider in the final result.

The result as follows:

```
customer ID     attribute1  attribute2  attribute3  ……  attribute N
Customer1       1               0            1              1   
Customer2       1               0            1              1   
Customer3       1               0            0              0
```

etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple little procedure

```
Sub MergeData()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim i As Long, ii As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet

        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1

            If .Cells(i, "A").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "A").Value Then

                For ii = 3 To lastcol

                    .Cells(i - 1, ii).Value = -(.Cells(i - 1, ii).Value > 0 OR .Cells(i, ii).Value > 0)
                Next ii

                .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next i

        .Columns(2).Delete
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I've changed the original response as you mentioned (putting it in a comment was less than clear)

Comment: Thank you very much "Bob Phillips" for your great code , i need only small modification , 
for final result each customer .. in your code you are count no. of 1 and in my case i need max value so in my interest result i interest for result 1 and 0 , can you place max to chose whatever values if 0 or 1 its produce 1 only , thanks again

Comment: I don't know how my comment appears before yours as I wrote it after yours? Anyway, my original response is edited as you requested.

Answer (score 1):

VBA is not required for this. Select all your data and DATA > Outline - Subtotal:

At each change in:  `customer ID`
Use function: Max
Add subtotals to: check each of the `attributes` (only)
Check Replace current subtotals and Summary below data
OK

Copy and Paste Special..., Values over the top. Filter to select for ColumnA, Text Filters, Contains..., Max, OK, select visible data (excluding last row if not wanted), copy and paste where required.  Delete ColumnB.